# Include 0 value days on barchart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I currently have a grouped dataframe of dates and values that I am creating a bar chart of:

```
 date   |  value
--------|--------
7-9-19  |   250
7-14-19 |   400
7-20-19 |   500
7-20-19 |   300
7-21-19 |   200
7-30-19 |   142
```

When I plot the df, I get back a bar chart only showing the days that have a value. Is there a way for me to easily plot a bar chart with all the days for the month without inserting dates and 0 values for all the missing days in the dataframe ?

**Edit: I left out that certain dates may have more than one entry, so adding the missing dates by re-indexing throws a duplicate axis error.

*** Solution - I ended up using just the day of the month to simplify having to deal with the datetime objs. ie, 7-9-19 => 9 . After a helpful suggestion by Quang Hoang below, I realized I could do this a little bit easier using just the day #:

```
ind = range(1,32)
df = df.reindex(ind, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reindex`, remember to set `date` as index:

```
# convert to datetime
# skip if already is
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m-%d-%y')

(df.set_index('date')
   .reindex(pd.date_range('2019-07-01','2019-07-31', freq='D'))
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, this would help, but I wasn't clear in my example df. Certain dates have duplicates, so there may be more than one value for the same date which gives me a duplicate axis error when trying to reindex

Comment: You would need to decide what to do with those duplicates, e.g. drop/average/sum. Otherwise, you would have two bars for the same date on the graph, which doesn't really make sense, does it?

Comment: Hm. They are being grouped and averaged before plotting, so I suppose I could try this re-indexing before sending to plot.. let's see

Comment: Yes, `df.groupby().reindex()` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions helped me think about this a little differently, and I came up with a simple solution. (Edited into original question for others)